# Error importing module flask.ext.mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

So I am trying to create a web app that is linked to a MySQL database using Python, Flask and MySQLDB. I went to MySQLDBs documentation [here](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

I have copied the code from the documentation correctly, yet I continue to get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mysqldb
```

This is how I have my code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import views
```

views.py

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm on Windows 10 if it matters.

Comment: Did you install Flask-MySQLdb?

Comment: Yeah. I used the command: pip install flask-mysqldb

Comment: Is that pip associated with the same Python interpreter you're using to run your application?

Comment: I think so. it's running in a virtual environment where Flask, Python and pip all reside and I only run python/pip from those folders in the virtual environment

Comment: Try `import flask_mysqldb`

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue using this way

Answer (score 1):

Try import it like so:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

The author also import it like this in his [example](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb/blob/master/examples/app.py) from github.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue using this way